# Xamarin NSNotificationCenter: When to call RemoveObserver?

Tags: c#, ios, memory-leaks, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my `UIViewController`, `viewDidLoad` method I am subscribing to a notification as follows:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad();

   this.disposable = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("UserUpdated", () => UserUpdated());
}
```

My question is where do I remove the observer so that there is no memory leak. Normally in Objective-C, I would remove it in the `dealloc` method.

But if I try to `Dispose` the `disposable` above in the `Dispose` method or in the destructor, there is a memory leak because of a cycle. What is the best way to prevent this memory cycle?

Note: I cannot use `ViewWillAppear/ViewWillDisappear` as my methods to add/remove the observer since I need access to it when the view of the view controller is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about my own experiences regarding memory leaks in Xamarin.iOS [here](https://thomasbandt.com/xamarinios-memory-pitfalls).

tl;dr: Use `ViewDidDisappear` and check if the controller is actually be popped or dismissed, to clean up.

Comment: In ViewDidDisappear how do you know that the controller is no longer used? My controller is a part of UITabBarController. So it doesn't get popped from a UINavigationController or dismissed.